# Jest + supertest in NodeJS, async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, jestjs

I try to test my api with Jest. I want more abstraction, so i created this function:

```js
const tokensConfig = config.get('test.tokens');

function testIt(method = 'get', url = '/', statuses = [], body = {}) {
      const testNames = ['unauthorized', 'user', 'admin'];
      const tokens = [null, tokensConfig.user, tokensConfig.admin];
    
      for (let i = 0; i < testNames.length; i++) {
        test(testNames[i], async () => {
          const response = await request(app)
            [method](url)
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .set('Authorization', tokens[i])
            .send(body);
          expect(response.statusCode).toBe(statuses[i]);
        });
      }
    }
```

In test.js file i run:

```js
const config  = require('config');
const request = require('supertest');
const testIt  = require('./testIt');
const app     = require('../app');

// It's work
describe('get user by email', () => {
    testIt('get', '/users/get-by-email/user@test', [401, 403, 200]);
  });
  
// It's not work  
describe('delete user', async () => {
    const userByEmail = await request(app)
      .get('/users/get-by-email/user@test')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', config.get('test.tokens.admin'));

    testIt('delete', `/users/${userByEmail._id}`, [401, 403, 200]);
  });
```

Trouble in async/await - testIt running before request user.

If i move test (or it) to describe block from function testIt and create request user inside test, it will work. But i want more abstraction (test block very big for many tests)

How fix it?

Comment: What is `test` inside `testIt`?

Comment: I don't think  `describe` support async functions.

Comment: @Bergi good catch, thats definitely it. `describe` describes a set of tests with `it`

Comment: I understand, that describe don't support async/await. 
If i move test (or it) to describe block from function testIt, it will work.
But i want more abstraction (test block very big fro many tests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result, i had to move the **test** to test.js:

```js
// test.js

it('delete user', async () => {
    const userByEmail = await request(app)
      .get('/users/get-by-email/user@test')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', config.get('test.tokens.admin'));

    const result = await testIt('delete', `/users/${userByEmail.body._id}`);
    expect(result).toEqual([401, 403, 401, 200]);
  });
```

```js
// testIt.js

const config  = require('config');
const request = require('supertest');
const app     = require('../app');

const tokensConfig = config.get('test.tokens');

async function testIt(method = 'get', url = '/', body = {}) {
  const testNames = ['unauthorized', 'user', 'adminTokenExpired', 'admin'];
  const tokens = [null, tokensConfig.userTokenInfinity, tokensConfig.adminTokenExpired, tokensConfig.adminTokenInfinity];
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < testNames.length; i++) {
    const response = await request(app)
      [method](url)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', tokens[i])
      .send(body);

    result.push(response.statusCode);
  }

  return result;
}

module.exports = testIt;
```

But i had to confine myself to one answer to all roles instead individual answer to every role, because i want less code.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need to let jest know that the expect is an async method, with `resolves`.

Here is the sample code from Jest's documentation:

```
// async/await can be used.
it('works with async/await', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const data = await user.getUserName(4);
  expect(data).toEqual('Mark');
});

// async/await can also be used with `.resolves`.
it('works with async/await and resolves', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  await expect(user.getUserName(5)).resolves.toEqual('Paul');
});
```

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#async-await